# Kubernetes cluster refused to connect google cloud

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, cluster-computing

while creating the container in google cloud getting below error

"http://localhost:8080/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/default/deployments?fieldManager=kubectl-create&fieldValidation=Strict": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused

Comment: Hi Bruce, could you please elaborate a bit further? Do you have other errors? Have you checked the logs in Stackdriver? The more information and accurate it is the more chances you'll get that somebody helps you.
Regards